# How to update shipping calculations on change of custom shipping field in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I have added new custom shipping field ( select option ) to woocommerce checkout page.

I am using that for shipping calculations.

that works perfect as well. but issue is while I change values in that field it do not update instantly.

It gives correct calculations on next page, after page submit.
I need it to work as change in custom field.

How to trigger WooCommerce Ajax which updates shipping calculation on change of my custom field ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually extremely simple to do if you are adding your fields in the correct way(using the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter). The only thing you need to do is to add the classes `address-field` and `update_totals_on_change` like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['shipping']['custom_field'] = array(
        'label' => 'Custom field',
        'required' => 1,
        'class' => array ('address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' )
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: hi, i can see in the console, for the custom check out fields  that we add, 'update_totals_on_change' class .... it is calling 'woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table' but it is not 'calculate_shipping' function is not called ?       Can anyone help on this mater?

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I included your code exactly, but the cart did not refresh when the field value changed and focus moved away from the field.

Comment: @QuantumDynamix You have to know, that it will be fired only if you fill other "addres-field" fields. Then when you change your custom field it will refresh.